# how to connect netbeans with git repository. we need to put some data into git using netbeans

Tags: java, git, netbeans, connection, repository

We want to store data to Git repository.
its our first time to encounter this type of application. so
can someone give us a hand? we need to store data into the repository using netbeans. thankyou so much Stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

To connect to an existing git repository use the menu option 
Team -> Git -> Clone ..., or Team -> Remote -> Clone ... if you already have a git project selected or Team -> Other VCS -> Git -> Clone ... if you have subversion or mercurial project selected.

This will open up a dialog where you enter the git repository URL.
such as `https://github.com/user/project.git`

To upload new data to the repo, add or modify what ever files you want. Select the project in the projects tab or the directory in the files tab. Right-click then select Git -> Commit ... from pop-up menu to commit the changes. Right-click again and select Git -> Remote -> Push to Upstream to upload the changes to the repository.

See [Using Git Support in NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html)